# memory allocation error /circle detection /opencv / c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I get memory allocation error when I debug this code and reach to the HoughCircles line:

```
#define CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT 3;
Mat Valv;
if( sumValv[0] > sumHol[0]){
  vector<Vec3f> circles;
  HoughCircles( Valv, circles, 3 , 1, Valv.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );
}
```

does enybody know what is the reason?

Comment: Maybe unrelated: Are you sure you meant `sumValv[0] > sumValv[0]`? It's always false.

Comment: @leemes: I corrected it :)

Comment: @leemes: Do you have any idea now?

Comment: Nope; I don't know OpenCV. In general, such errors can't be found by only showing a few lines of code. You need to debug your code, maybe use some memory analyzer program like valgrind. The source of the error may be at a totally different place. Also pay attention to any compiler warning.

Answer (score 5):

Valv is not initialized before use of HoughCircles. You can't find a circle in image that does not exist...

Comment: you mean I should initialize the Mat first?!

Comment: Yes, of course. Input of HoughCircles is image (that supposedly has circles). And its output is array of circles that were found in input image. It can't run without input.

Comment: it is obvious that I should fill in the Mat with the data. This code is part of a big code. I just wrote Mat Valv; to show that its type is Mat :)

Comment: Eh sorry. I thought that you used it as it was written here. But the question remains: are you 100% sure that the Valv exists. Can you print its width and height prior to HoughCircles?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the Mat Valv was 32 bit while it should be 8bit in  opencv. so, I changed its type to int. It works well now :)